# Python: Random numbers into a list

Tags: python, list, random

Create a 'list' called my_randoms of 10 random numbers between 0 and 100.

This is what I have so far:

```
import random
my_randoms=[]
for i in range (10):
    my_randoms.append(random.randrange(1, 101, 1))
    print (my_randoms)
```

Unfortunately Python's output is this:

```
[34]
[34, 30]
[34, 30, 75]
[34, 30, 75, 27]
[34, 30, 75, 27, 8]
[34, 30, 75, 27, 8, 58]
[34, 30, 75, 27, 8, 58, 10]
[34, 30, 75, 27, 8, 58, 10, 1]
[34, 30, 75, 27, 8, 58, 10, 1, 59]
[34, 30, 75, 27, 8, 58, 10, 1, 59, 25]
```

It generates the 10 numbers like I ask it to, but it generates it one at a time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put your print after the for loop...rather than in it.

Comment: Actually, you are generating the numbers one at a time, but your original code has you printing the values each time one is generated. The solutions below that talk about the print statement simply wait and print the list after all the numbers are generated.

Comment: Computers programs in Python always do one thing at a time. Every program is a sequence of very tiny steps. Now, the question then becomes "What steps do I want completed when I print the list?". And you, apparently, want all the random numbers to be added to the list before you print it. If you remove the indent before the print it will execute after all the steps of the for loop have executed repeatedly. Indented the print is part of the sequence of steps executed as the list is built.

Comment: ```xrange``` is now ```range```, python 3.x onwards.

Answer (score 97):

You could use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.sample) to generate the list with one call:

```
import random
my_randoms = random.sample(range(100), 10)
```

That generates numbers in the (inclusive) range from 0 to 99. If you want 1 to 100, you could use this (thanks to @martineau for pointing out my convoluted solution):

```
my_randoms = random.sample(range(1, 101), 10)
```

Comment: Sample won't include duplicate values, which may or may not matter in this use case, but worth noting

Comment: For values in the range of 1..100 it would be simpler to use `random.sample(xrange(1, 101), 10)` than a list comprehension.

Comment: for python3 `my_randoms = random.sample(range(100), 10)`

Comment: I get an error that 'xrange' is not defined. Do I miss any libraries?

Comment: @thanos.a `xrange` doesn't exist anymore in Python 3, but you can use `range` instead: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-vs-xrange-python/

Answer (score 53):

```
import random
my_randoms = [random.randrange(1, 101, 1) for _ in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 19):

Fix the indentation of the `print` statement:

```
import random

my_randoms=[]
for i in range (10):
    my_randoms.append(random.randrange(1,101,1))

print (my_randoms)
```

This works because you are printing `my_randoms` each time one of the values is generated. By unindenting the `print()` statement, it is placed outside the loop and only executed once after the for loop has finished.

Comment: For other beginners (future readers), perhaps expand with an explanation regarding indentation error?

Comment: This is actually the only answer that addresses OP's query. Others are good of course, but they just improve/provide alternative on syntax, or methods, etc. 
OP's problem was just indentation, guys !

Answer (score 13):

**This is way late but in-case someone finds this helpful.**

You could use list comprehension.

```
rand = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(1, 11)]
print(rand)
```

Output:

```
[974, 440, 305, 102, 822, 128, 205, 362, 948, 751]
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

Here I use the `sample` method to generate 10 random numbers between 0 and 100.

*Note*: I'm using Python 3's `range` function (not `xrange`).

```
import random

print(random.sample(range(0, 100), 10))
```

The output is placed into a ***list***:

```
[11, 72, 64, 65, 16, 94, 29, 79, 76, 27]
```

Comment: Actually, between 0 and 99 without replacement.

Answer (score 4):

`xrange()` will not work for 3.x.

`numpy.random.randint().tolist()` is a great alternative for integers in a specified interval:

```
 #[In]:
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123) #option for reproducibility
np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=10).tolist()

#[Out:]

[66, 92, 98, 17, 83, 57, 86, 97, 96, 47]
```

You also have `np.random.uniform()` for floats:

```
#[In]:
np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=10).tolist()

#[Out]:
[69.64691855978616,
28.613933495037948,
22.68514535642031,
55.13147690828912,
71.94689697855631,
42.3106460124461,
98.07641983846155,
68.48297385848633,
48.09319014843609,
39.211751819415056]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

a=[]
n=int(input("Enter number of elements:"))

for j in range(n):
       a.append(random.randint(1,20))

print('Randomised list is: ',a)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A short explanation regarding what he was doing wrong, as requested, would be great.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution:**

```
indices=[]
for i in range(0,10):
  n = random.randint(0,99)
  indices.append(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The one random list generator in the `random` module not mentioned here is `random.choices`:

```
my_randoms = random.choices(range(0, 100), k=10)
```

It's like `random.sample` but with replacement. The sequence passed doesn't have to be a range; it doesn't even have to be numbers. The following works just as well:

```
my_randoms = random.choices(['a','b'], k=10)
```

If we compare the runtimes, among random list generators, `random.choices` is the fastest no matter the size of the list to be created. However, for larger lists/arrays, numpy options are much faster. So for example, if you're creating a random list/array to assign to a pandas DataFrame column, then using `np.random.randint` is the fastest option.

[image]

Code used to produce the above plot:

```
import perfplot
import numpy as np
import random

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: n,
    kernels=[
        lambda n: [random.randint(0, n*2) for x in range(n)],
        lambda n: random.sample(range(0, n*2), k=n), 
        lambda n: [random.randrange(n*2) for i in range(n)],
        lambda n: random.choices(range(0, n*2), k=n), 
        lambda n: np.random.rand(n), 
        lambda n: np.random.randint(0, n*2, size=n),
        lambda n: np.random.choice(np.arange(n*2), size=n),
    ],
    labels=['random_randint', 'random_sample', 'random_randrange', 'random_choices', 
            'np_random_rand', 'np_random_randint', 'np_random_choice'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(17)],
    equality_check=None,
    xlabel='~n'
)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
my_randoms = [randint(n1,n2) for x in range(listsize)]
```