# Comparing elements in a list with its neighbours

Tags: python

I have a list of 29400 values in Python and I'm trying to check if each element of the list is larger than both the 2000 neighbors to its left and the 2000 neighbors to its right. If the element is larger than its 4000 neighbors, I want to retrieve the index of the element. If there aren't 2000 neighbors to the right I just want to compare it with future elements until I reach the end of the list, and vice versa if there aren't 2000 values to the left.

```
def find_peaks(t):
prev = []
future = []
peak_index = []
for i in range(len(t)-2000): # compare element with previous values
    for j in range(1,2001):
        if t[i]<t[i+j]:
            prev.append(False)
            break
        if j==2000:
            if t[i]<t[i+j]:
                prev.append(False)
                break
            prev.append(True)

for i in range(1999,len(t)-1): # compare element with future values
    for j in range(1,2001):
        if t[i]<t[i-j]:
            future.append(False)
            break
        if j==2000:
            if t[i]<t[i-j]:
                future.append(False)
                break
            future.append(True)
future = future[::-1] # reverse list
for i in range(0,len(prev)-1):
    if prev[i] == True:
        if prev[i] == True:
            peak_index.append(i)
```

Does anyone know of any better ways to go about this? I was having trouble comparing elements near the end and the beginning of the list- If there aren't 2000 elements left in the list for me to compare with, then the list wraps around to the beginning of the list, which isn't something I want.

Comment: Do you want circular behaviour for your list. What I mean to say is if there are lets say 10k element in your list and you are comparing the first element to start with, then there are no elements to compare on its left. So you want to compare it with the rear end in reverese order as well ? or you skip comparing it on the left side ? Did I made myself clear enough ?

Comment: No, I don't want circular behavior. If I was comparing say, the 3rd element, I would just want to compare it with the 1st and 2nd element on the left and with the 2000 elements on the right. I'm new to python and programming in general, there's probably an easier way of going about it, I'm just not aware.

Comment: Okay I got your point, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some list comprehension, so the actual search becomes a one-liner. I cannot judge about speed and beauty, but it takes just some seconds on my machine.

```
import random

# create list of random numbers and manually insert two peaks
t = [random.randrange(1, 1000) for r in range(29400)]  # found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655089/python-random-numbers-into-a-list
t[666] = 2000
t[6666] = 2000

# finds the peak elements
peaks = [index for index, value in enumerate(t) if value == max(t[max(index-2000, 0):min(index+2000, len(t))])]
print peaks  # includes 666 and 6666
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive, iterative version would be to go through each element and do look behind/ahead a certain number of times to see if there are values larger than it, and if not consider it a pick:

```
def find_peaks(data, span=2000):
    peaks = []
    for i, value in enumerate(data):
        peak = False  # start with the assumed non-peak
        for j in range(max(0, i - 1), max(0, i - span - 1), -1):  # look behind
            peak = value > data[j]  # check if our value is larger than the selected neighbor
            if not peak:  # not a peak, break away
                break
        if peak:  # look behind passed, look ahead:
            for j in range(i + 1, min(i + span + 1, len(data))):
                if value <= data[j]:  # look ahead failed, break away
                    peak = False
                    break
            if peak:  # if look ahead passed...
                peaks.append(i)  # add it to our peaks list
    return peaks
```

This is the most performant way to do it with look ahead/behind as it breaks away immediately when a condition is not met instead of checking every element with every element.

If you want to count in the neighbors that are of the same value when calculating a peak (so your current peak candidate is the same) you can use `peak = value >= data[j]` in the look behind and `if value < data[j]` in the look ahead portions.

Answer (score 0):

My solution does not involve any language powerful inbuilt methods. Its just plain logic to find the target peaks. Basically I am iterating over each element and then in inner loop checking if its previous or future neighbors are present and less than the current element. I am initializing a `isPeak` variable to `True` for if none of the neighbors in both direction are greater than the current element, which indicates your current element is peak element. After that just getting the index of target element.

```
def find_peaks(t , neighbour_length=2000):
    peak_index = []
    for i in range(len(t)): # compare element with previous values
        isPeak = True #intialize to true
        for j in range(i, neighbour_length + i):

            # Check if previous index value is present
            if (2*i-j-1 >= 0):
                # Check if next neighbour is less or break
                if(t[i] <= t[2*i-j-1]):
                    isPeak = False
                    break
            # Check if Future element is present
            if (j+i+1 < len(t)):
                #Check if next future neighbour ir less or break
                if(t[i] <= t[i+j+1]):
                    isPeak = False
                    break

        if(isPeak):
            peak_index.append(i)

    return peak_index
```

Hope it Helps!