# How to generate random number into an empty list multiple time

Tags: python-3.x, random, dice

Lets say I want to find all the numbers a fair die can roll `sample_size` of times.

I first create a empty list

```
die_list= []
def die_number(sample_size)：
    for i in range(sample_size) #i want to iterate what ever the sample_size is
    die_list.append(random.randint(0,7))
```

is this thought process correct?

Comment: First of all, your code has a couple of syntax errors. I suggest you fix those first, to separate the question about "thought process" from syntax errors. As for generating the list of random numbers, see [Python: Random numbers into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16655089/2745495)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample code provided,you can try this out using list comprehension

```
import random

def die_number(sample_size):
  return [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(sample_size)]

die_number(5)

[29, 0, 2, 100, 51]
```