# how to fill your list with 100 random numbers

Tags: python

```
from random import  randint
scores = []
x = randint(0,100)
for x in range(0,101):
    scores.append(x)
print(scores)
```

prints numbers from 0 -100 :( instead of random int

Comment: try `scores = [randint(1,100) for i in range(101)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Random numbers into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655089/python-random-numbers-into-a-list)

Comment: Funny how all the answerers copied `range(0,101)` while the question is to create 100 random numbers and this creates 101 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `randint` function call inside the `for-loop`:

```
from random import randint
scores = []
for _ in range(0,101):
    x = randint(0,100)
    scores.append(x)
print(scores)
```

Also you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
scores = [randint(0,100) for _ in range(101)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import  randint
scores = []
for x in range(0,101):
    scores.append(randint(0,100))
print(scores)
```